# IMPORTRANGE with filter

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I want to do an IMPORTRANGE with a filter, where it only pulls through data if a cell in column C contains a term that is listed in another column G.

**I need columns A:E to import from another sheet, if the column C data appears in column G somewhere, on the current sheet.**

This is what I have done which isn't correct but can't work it out:

=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL","Sheet1!A2:E"),"select * where $C='$G:$G'")

Please see the image below:

[image]

Comment: To make things easier for the community, can you please provide a link of the sample of your sheet or a copy that can be used for testing?

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL", "Sheet1!A2:E"),
 "where Col3 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, G:G)&"'")
```